# In AOSP of Android 12 I am getting error "java.lang.NullPointerException: getInstance(requireContext()) must not be null" while using AppWidgetManager

Tags: android, android-source, automotive

In AOSP of Android 12 I am getting error "java.lang.NullPointerException: getInstance(requireContext()) must not be null" at runtime while using AppWidgetManager.
"mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(requireContext())"

Answer (score 1):

getContext() returns a nullable Context.

requireContext() returns a nonnull Context, or throws an exception when one isn't available.

If your code is in a lifecycle phase where you know your fragment is attached to a context, just use requireContext() to get a Context and also keep static analyzers happy about potential NPE issues.

If your code is outside of regular fragment lifecycle (say, an async callback), you might be better off using getContext(), checking its return value yourself and only proceeding using it if it was non-null.

Being explicit with nullability is even more important in Kotlin where it is built into the language's type system.

Comment: Thank you Mohamed for your quick reply. However, I have tried all above mentioned ways still no luck.